# Authentication always using an old token value

Tags: authentication, postman, identityserver4, abp

I have a problem that I don't know how to resolve. I have a microservice model (based on the [Volo ABP Microservice Demo](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Samples/Microservice-Demo)) for my project, I have an API with all the methods to retrieve data, an AuthServer that acts as the authority for all my projects, and a gateway that translates the requests.

This is how I have configured my authentication in my `Gateway` project:

```
public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
{
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
    var configuration = context.Services.GetConfiguration();

    Configure<AbpMultiTenancyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.IsEnabled = SidesysMicroservicesConsts.IsMultiTenancyEnabled;
    });

    context.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
            options.ApiName = configuration["AuthServer:ApiName"];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });

    context.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "VirtualSpace Gateway API", Version = "v1" });
        options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) => true);
        options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName);
    });

    context.Services.AddOcelot(context.Services.GetConfiguration());

    Configure<AbpDbContextOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer();
    });

    context.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(DefaultCorsPolicyName, builder =>
        {
            builder
                .WithOrigins(
                    configuration["App:CorsOrigins"]
                        .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(o => o.RemovePostFix("/"))
                        .ToArray()
                )
                .WithAbpExposedHeaders()
                .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
    });

    //context.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
    //{
    //    options.Configuration = configuration["Redis:Configuration"];
    //});

    //var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configuration["Redis:Configuration"]);
    //context.Services.AddDataProtection()
    //    .PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis, "MsDemo-DataProtection-Keys");
}
```

I have roles and different users in my Database so to retrieve a token I use the `/connect/token` URL from the AuthServer with the respective role, for this, I use Postman with the corresponding headers. Once I retrieved the token I need, I would use Postman with the corresponding URL from the `Gateway` (my gateway runs on port 44377) with the respective "Authorization" header and its token value with a "Bearer" authentication scheme, this request will translate to the URL to their corresponding API (it runs on port 44320) URL request that I need to do, for example, `http://localhost:44377/api/virtualspaceattention/GetSourceUsers`, it would be translated to `http://localhost:44320//api/virtualspaceattention/VirtualSpaceAttention/GetSourceUsers`.

Problem here is that no matter what token I use, every time I get the same log error:

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44377/api/virtualspaceattention/GetSoruceUsers - -
2022-01-07 17:00:47.928 -03:00 [INF] Failed to validate the token.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: 
kid: 'C99C917C5E43906FE6A88DDF28E73628'.
Exceptions caught:
 ''. 
token: '{"alg":"RS256","kid":"C99C917C5E43906FE6A88DDF28E73628","typ":"at+jwt"}.{"nbf":1640913147,"exp":1672449147,"iss":"http://localhost/authserver","aud":["VirtualSpace","VirtualSpaceGateway"],"client_id":"virtualSpace","iat":1640913147,"scope":["VirtualSpace","VirtualSpaceGateway"]}'.
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
2022-01-07 17:00:48.025 -03:00 [INF] Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: 
kid: 'C99C917C5E43906FE6A88DDF28E73628'.
Exceptions caught:
 ''. 
token: '{"alg":"RS256","kid":"C99C917C5E43906FE6A88DDF28E73628","typ":"at+jwt"}.{"nbf":1640913147,"exp":1672449147,"iss":"http://localhost/authserver","aud":["VirtualSpace","VirtualSpaceGateway"],"client_id":"virtualSpace","iat":1640913147,"scope":["VirtualSpace","VirtualSpaceGateway"]}'.
```

I've compared the token I retrieved through the `/connect/token` URL and is not the same as the one that the request is currently using. I've checked its properties using the [JWT website](https://jwt.io/) and It seems it is using a token that is somewhere cached but I don't know where it is to deal with it.

I will paste here the values from the [JWT website](https://jwt.io/) for comparison:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "1C700F5BA873DCA75C9CEC6B36118026",
  "typ": "at+jwt"
}
{
  "nbf": 1641586212,
  "exp": 1673122212,
  "iss": "http://localhost:44399",
  "aud": [
    "VirtualSpace",
    "VirtualSpaceGateway"
  ],
  "client_id": "virtualSpace",
  "sub": "87861a01-4486-17b8-c6d6-3a01476f3851",
  "auth_time": 1641586212,
  "idp": "local",
  "tenantid": "0a1ea190-866c-3522-010e-3a014784d83d",
  "operator_description": "Operador 1",
  "role": "operator",
  "email": "operator.one@sidesys.com",
  "email_verified": "False",
  "name": "operatorOne",
  "iat": 1641586212,
  "scope": [
    "VirtualSpace",
    "VirtualSpaceGateway"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

Two things I've found comparing the token:

- The "iss": "http://localhost:44399", and "iss": "http://localhost/authserver", these values are different. I used to run my AuthServer through IIS but I'm not anymore.
- "kid": "1C700F5BA873DCA75C9CEC6B36118026" and "kid": "C99C917C5E43906FE6A88DDF28E73628". These are definitely not the same. Again, it seems that this old token is stored somewhere.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the browser. It seems that Google Chrome stores the `token` in the `Application` tab even if you have the `Disable cache` option selected. And even if you force the page to empty the cache and force the reload, the `token` will remain there.

In the `Application` tab, you need to clean everything under the `Storage` section in order to fix this issue. Honestly a nightmare, I lost practically the entire day trying to come up with a solution until I realized this.